# Can't get bootstrap to apply to my code

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap to style my page, and I have it linked with 
`<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` which is what given on the website. But bootstrap won't apply when I run my code. I have them in the same folder.

Comment: Can you give more details on your setup?  As worded, this is a very vague question.

Comment: Are your stylesheets included?

Comment: Where did you include your bootstrap css?

Comment: You should review your question while you type, or **at least** before posting. Inline code fragments should go between backquotes, (use the icons above the edit text, or Ctrl+K) so that the system doens't see HTML fragments as markup.

Comment: Your path suggests that `bootstrap.min.css` should be in a subfolder

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap should be the first css link in your head tag, after that the other css links. I don't really know what you mean with "I have them in the same folder." but I hope you mean that you have the bootstrap css files in your css folder.

Try putting it at the top like this:

```
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- General CSS -->
<link href="css/general.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- font awesome CSS link -->
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Javascript here -->
</head>
```

You can also try to use the bootstrap.css file. This will probably be the one you'll be editing as well.